# Shuffling Text Animation with CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want to display the word 'Hello' on the home page of a website. I used CSS to make the 'Hello' transition up as the page loads in the beginning. I would like to implement a shuffling animation that randomly shuffles between the word Hello in different languages. I would like to do so with an animation where as the 'Hello' slides up at the beginning, the 'Hello' slides up more, fades out and disappears. As this occurs, a 'Bonjour' for example slides up from beneath and takes place. I picture this repeating forever.

Is there any way to implement such animation using CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, or any other web tools? Below is the HTML, CSS, and JS structure I have that only achieves the initial transition as the page loads:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <h1 id="switch">Hello</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

```
section {
    text-align: left;
}
section h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 420;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 200px;

    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY( 43px );
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var hello = new Array( 'Hello', 'Bonjour', 'Hola' );

function randomIndex( ) { 
    return Math.floor( Math.random( ) * hello.length);
};

window.setInterval( function( ) {
    var newIndex = randomIndex( );
    while( newIndex === currentIndex ) newIndex = randomIndex();
    currentIndex = newIndex;
    document.getElementById("switch").textContent = hello[ currentIndex ]; 
}, 2300 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS you need to set up `@keyframes` for your `fade-in` ***animation***,. Then you can add a ***percentage*** of the duration that you wish to animate the *animate-able* properties ***opacity*** and ***top*** position. Make sure your duration matches the ***setInterval*** time => `2300` => `2.3s`.

### @keyframes:

In my example I set up a tween that will start at `0%` with ***opacity 0*** and ***top*** *position* in ***vh*** lengths, then as the tween reaches `70%`, it is shown moving upwards to `5vh`, where it will stay at an ***opacity*** of `1` until `90%`, when its ***opacity*** will *start to fade out*. At `100%` it will be ***opacity*** of `0`, then the loop starts over as it is set to `infinte` in the css animation, the element will reset to `20vh` and the animation repeats itself over again.

**You can play around with the percentages in the @keyframes rule to get the effect you're look for in terms of fading in and out movement, etc...*

```js
let currentIndex = 0;
const hello = ['Hello', 'Bonjour', 'Hola'];

function randomIndex() {
  return ~~(Math.random() * hello.length);
};

window.setInterval(function() {
  let newIndex = randomIndex();
  while (newIndex === currentIndex) newIndex = randomIndex();
  currentIndex = newIndex;
  document.getElementById("switch").textContent = hello[currentIndex];
}, 2300);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 420;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 50vh;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 2.3s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 20vh;
  }
  70%,
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 5vh;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 5vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <h1 id="switch">Hello</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the greeting is not really semantic (you don't for example want it read out every few seconds to a screen reader) you could put it instead on the body (or another suitable element, depending on exactly the structure you want) in a pseudo before element. That way it is basically decoration, not meaning.

Also, to avoid timing issues, where a setInterval may get out of step with the timing of the keyframes animation, you can sense the animationend event and then set a timout for the next 300ms and then reset the animation to run again.

```js
let currentIndex = 0;
const hello = ['Hello', 'Bonjour', 'Hola'];

function randomIndex() {
  return ~~(Math.random() * hello.length);
};

function getNext() {
  let newIndex = randomIndex();
  while (newIndex === currentIndex) newIndex = randomIndex();
  currentIndex = newIndex;
  document.body.style.setProperty('--greeting', "'" + hello[currentIndex] + "'");
  document.body.style.setProperty('--animationname', 'none');
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.style.setProperty('--animationname', 'move');
  }, 300);
}
document.body.addEventListener('animationend',getNext);
```

```css
body {
  --greeting: 'Hello';
  --animationname: move;
}
body::before {
  content: var(--greeting);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: var(--animationname);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 420;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Obviously you'll want to change the timings, positionings etc to be exactly what you want.